# SharePoint Color Palette Tool

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

Could anybody please explain me about SharePoint Color Palette Tool and whether the effort required for branding a site using SharePoint Color Palette tool is similar to effort taken using Microsoft Visual Studio (Customizing Master Page and Css)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Color Palette Tool is for creating color themes and has very limited branding option compared to custom master page and css.

With custom master page and css you have full control, but be aware that you'll have to re-do the branding work with the major upgrades (upgrade sp2010 to 2013, 2013 to 2016 etc.), and you'll also miss any minor update that affects the default master page unless you include those updates yourself in your custom master page as they are released.

Applying only a custom theme has limited options but you don't have to worry for SP minor of major updates.